# Ignite and Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gridgain, ignite

How do I use Ignite with Spring Boot? I googled it but without success. Has anyone experience with the combination of Spring Boot and Ignite?

Is that the correct way to run Ignite in with Spring Boot?
[Apache Ignite Loading Twice with Spring-Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469813/apache-ignite-loading-twice-with-spring-boot)

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is now direct integration with Spring Boot, so you should manually start a node within the application using `Ignition.start()` method.

Answer (score 2):

I've got test project spring boot + ignite. I hope that will help:
[github project](https://github.com/Normal/apache-ignite-testproject)

Answer (score 1):

For me use case, i create a bean and start ignite inside it after that return the ignite. it will start ignite only one time at start time.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Use following steps to integrate ignite with spring boot.

1. Add following dependency in POM.xml file
     
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
   <artifactId>ignite-spring-data</artifactId>
   <version>${ignite.version}</version>
 </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency> 
2. Create the Ignite bean instance
    @Bean
 public Ignite igniteInstance() {
     IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        Ignite igniteInst= Ignition.start(cfg);
        return igniteInst;
    }
3. Configure the repository
@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "cacheName")
public interface RepositoryName extends IgniteRepository<V, K> {
}

4. Autowired the RepositoryName interface which extends the IgniteRepository in service layer

@Component
public class ServiceImpl 
@Autowired
RepositoryName  repositoryName; 
}

5. You can use 5th steps apart from 4th steps to inject the ignite bean in service layer
@Component
public class ServiceImpl {
 @Autowired
 Ignite ignite;
    void abcMethod(){
     IgniteCache<K, V> igniteCache = ignite.cache("CacheName");
    }
}
```